# Keeping track of multiple SKAction's with the same key

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I am generating multiple SKActions within a few seconds of each other. These actions are positioning a sprite on the screen and moving it. When I generate the action, since it is the same sprite and same action, they have the same key name. I understand that if you generate a SKAction with the same key, the previous one is removed.

I need to somehow know when each one of these actions reaches a certain point on the screen. How could I keep track of the multiple actions even though they have the same key?

Comment: You could create a sequence action, splinting your move action into 2 actions and running a block, or performing selector to notify you. But I am not sure if you are interested in certain distance action run, or position of sprite. If you are after position of sprite you will be better of subclasing it and overriding setPosition method to check for changes there.

Comment: I think subclassing it would be the best way to go. Do you have an example on overriding setPosition to accomplish this?

Comment: I deleted my answer cause it seems action evades setPosition method :( The only way i can think of would be to use didEvaluateActions in your scene. And check for position after every action evaluation.